# jQuery - Selecting the first <a> in the first <td> of a <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following markup:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a>foo</a>
    </td>
    <td>bar</td>
    <td>
       <a class="delete-btn">delete</a>
    </td> 
</tr>
```

I've already hooked up a click event handler using jquery `$(".delete-btn")` the problem is that inside the click event handler I need the text of the first  element (foo).

I'm already getting the value I need with this call:

```
$(this).closest("tr").children().first().children().first("a")
```

but I feel it's too verbose. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: why not provide a complete example with a stack overflow js snippet?

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr').find('td:first-child a')`?

Comment: You should read about [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: @DavidThomas that was exactly what I needed. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't like this either, but... it's exactly what you're looking for:

```
$(this).closest("tr").find("> td:first-child > a");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of jQuery's `:first` pseudo-selector.

In this instance, your entire selector would be:

- `$('tr td:first a:first')` (for the first `<tr>` only)
- `$('tr').find('td:first a:first')` (for every `<tr>`)

**Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.delete-btn').click(function(){
        $('tr').find('td:first a:first').hide();
    })

});
```

```css
table, tr, td {
border: 1px solid rgb(191,191,191);
border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
padding: 12px;
}

.delete-btn {
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tr>
<td><a>foo</a></td>
<td>bar</td>
<td><a class="delete-btn">delete</a></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a>foo</a></td>
<td>bar</td>
<td><a>baz</a></td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yo did tip me in the right direction. And the code snippet is well done! however, using that selector, it would always return the first <a> of the first row. If the table has more than one row, I need to return the first <a> of every <tr>.

Comment: To return the first `<a>` of every `<tr>` you can swap `$('tr td:first a:first')` for `$('tr').find('td:first a:first')` - I have updated the example above.

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear enough on my intent. I have a table with several rows. when I click the link on the last cell, the event handler needs the text of the first link on the first cell of that particular row. @MaxArt and David Thomas both accomplish this.